# Does "allow only when the app is active" also include the background?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have to get the locations of my user even when the app is in the background. So my question is if my user only allows the application to get the locations when the app is active, does this "active" mean also active in the background?

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps can support one of two levels of location access.

**While using the app**

The app can access the device’s location when the app is in use. This is also known as “when-in-use authorization.”

**Always**

The app can access the device’s location either when app is in use or in the background.

so the answer of your question is NO, Location access is not active when app is in background with **While using the app** level.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there a way to "force" the user to choose Always ?

Comment: i think you can't do it.